# How to allow access to create terms in a specific vocabulary?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, users

If you remove "Administer vocabularies and terms" from a role in Drupal 8.4, but you want to give access to a role for a specific Vocabulary, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this for "create" access for terms in specific vocabularies.

For example, for a Vocabulary called "Author".

You are given the option to "Delete terms from Author" and "Edit terms in Author", but no option to "Create terms in Author".

[image]

How would you add this option a role in Drupal 8 after you have removed the "Administer vocabularies and terms" permission?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom permission: "Create new authors" in mymodule.permissions.yml:

```
create new authors:
  title: 'Create New Authors'
  description: 'Create New Author Taxonomy Terms'
  restrict access: true
```

Assign the new permission to the roles you want.

Then using hook__access_entity_create_access():

```
function mymodule__access_entity_create_access(\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account, array $context, $entity_bundle) {
  if ($entity_bundle == 'author' && $account->hasPermission('create new authors')) {
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }
  // No opinion.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

This will give explicit access to roles with your custom permission, and in other cases it will defer to the default drupal permissions.